# Concatenate sequence in format like 1-3,6,8-10,12

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have numbers, but not sequence. If these are in sequence, then the result should be like below.
If I have data like 1,2,3,6,8,9,10,12 etc..
I need the result like 1-3,6,8-10,12

Comment: In what language? For what application? Do you need the code? What have you tried?

Comment: Those are present in single column or different rows?

Comment: I need MS sql server statements/ Procedure to display that order

Comment: Please provide sample data in a table format and your expected result.

Comment: declare #Table Table(ID INT, Value Int)
insert into #Table
values(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(1,7),(1,8)
select * from #Table : Need the result like 1-3,5,7-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @Digits table (Value int primary key)
INSERT @Digits VALUES (1),(2),(3),(6),(8),(9),(10),(12)

SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(varchar(max),
(
    SELECT
        ',' + CASE 
            WHEN MIN(Value) = MAX(Value) THEN CONVERT(varchar(10), MIN(Value)) 
            ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10), MIN(Value)) + '-' + CONVERT(varchar(10), MAX(Value)) 
        END
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value) AS Seq, Value FROM @Digits) Data
    GROUP BY Value - Seq
    FOR XML PATH('')
)), 1, 1, '') AS Result
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1620)